Passing arguments to __enter__ when using a global variable
I'm using a global variable to store some useful data that I need across the whole execution of my code.
It's something like this:
config_object = None

def init_config(config_file=CONFIG_PATH):
    # some initialization code...
    global config_object
    config_object = U2DBLiveConfig(config_file)


def get_config():
    if not config_object:
        init_config()
    return config_object

I added __enter__ and __exit__ methods so I can set a flag when using the config object along a session object of other type
class U2DBLiveConfig:
    def __init__(self, config_file_path=CONFIG_PATH):
        self.__uopy_session_opened = False
        # rest of init code

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__uopy_session_opened = True
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.__uopy_session_opened = False

I use both objects in one with statement like this.
    with create_uopy_session() as uopy_session, get_config() as cfg:
        # here, the __uopy_session_opened flag is set to true

I'd like to pass the objetc uopy_session to the __enter__ method, so it can be accessed from the config_object elsewhere.
Please note that config_object may have been created before calling the with statement, so I can't pass it to the __init__.
Is there a way to do something like this?
class U2DBLiveConfig:
    def __init__(self, config_file_path=CONFIG_PATH):
        self.__uopy_session_opened = False
        self.__uopy_session = None
        # rest of init code

    def __enter__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__uopy_session_opened = True
        self.__uopy_session = kwargs['uopy_session']
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.__uopy_session_opened = False
        self.__uopy_session = None


a singleton to handle the config_object would be better (in my opinion , i may be wrong ) , where on creation of uopy_session this singleton got updated and cfg took this singleton data

Whether you implement the singleton pattern for the configuration (and I would not) seems orthogonal to the question.

You cannot pass arguments to __enter__ However, the class construction lifecycle is such that __init__ is called before __enter__ so you can pass your parameters in the constructor and reference them in __enter__

A single context manager that wraps create_uopy_session and gets the config would seem to be sufficient:
@contextlib.contextmanager
def uopy_session_with_cfg(session=None):
    if session is None:
        session = create_uopy_session()

    # s is only necessary if session.__enter__() doesn't return self.
    with session as s:
        yield s, get_config()
    


with uopy_session_with_cfg() as (session, cfg):
    ...


Ellaborating on @sahasrara62 comment I made my config object into a singleton:
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls._instances[cls](**kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class U2DBLiveConfig(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, config_file_path=CONFIG_PATH):
        self.__uopy_session = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs and 'uopy_session' in kwargs:
            self.__uopy_session = kwargs['uopy_session']

Now I can use the with statement like this:
with create_uopy_session() as uopy_session, U2DBLiveConfig(uopy_session) as cfg:
    # some code...

And I can assign the session to the configuration object.
